# How can I add a property in the slim markup language?

Tags: slim-lang

I'd like to add a property to a tag generated by slim. For example:

```
<input type='text' name='name' required>
```

Comment: was your issue solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create the HTML example you provided, your Slim would look like this:

```
 = text_field_tag :name, required: 'required'
```

To add any additional attributes to the `input` tag, you'd simply provide additional arguments to the `text_field_tag` method. So if you wanted to specify the `class` attribute, you could do:

```
 = text_field_tag :name, required: 'required', class: 'really-nice-text-field'
```

#### UPDATE:

This would also work:

```
 = text_field_tag :name, required: true
```